# MySQL-Connector does not work after using JLink in a JavaFx project

Tags: javafx, mysql-connector, jlink

I am trying to create an executable out of my JavaFX project that uses mysql-connector driver to connect to a local database. After i generate the JLink folder via the pom.xml file, when i run my application, the connection between the database and the app does not work (Running the application in the IDE makes everything work fine). I am using InteliJ as my IDE, MySQL for the database and i think the connector is a jar file without a module-info.jar file which is causing issues in JLink.

I did some digging and i found out that mysql-connector can not be added directly via Jlink. I've seen some workarounds (for example: [moditect](https://github.com/moditect/moditect)) but i still can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is not clear to you? the driver is loaded with reflection and therefore the dependency cannot be inferred automatically. just add it to the modules you want to include from jlink in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use jlink to directly create an executable file if your application is not fully modular. However, you can use a combination of jdeps, jlink and jpackage to create an application bundle or an installer. You might want to have a look at this tutorial: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX